# Trying to retrieve first 5 characters from string in bash error?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to retrieve the first 5 characters from a string and but keep getting a `Bad substitution` error for the string manipulation line, I have the following lines in my `teststring.sh` script:

```
TESTSTRINGONE="MOTEST"

NEWTESTSTRING=${TESTSTRINGONE:0:5}
echo ${NEWTESTSTRING}
```

I have went over the syntax many times and cant see what im doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Have you had any luck? What version of bash are you using? (`bash -version` or `bash --version`, typically)

Comment: @Mo. I also would like to encourage you to accept an answer below or at least give some feedback. Alex L's answer is very good imho, and its definitely worth some fake internet points!

Answer (score 81):

Depending on your shell, you may be able to use the following syntax:

```
expr substr $string $position $length
```

So for your example:

```
TESTSTRINGONE="MOTEST"
echo `expr substr ${TESTSTRINGONE} 0 5`
```

---

Alternatively,

```
echo 'MOTEST' | cut -c1-5
```

or

```
echo 'MOTEST' | awk '{print substr($0,0,5)}'
```

Answer (score 71):

`echo 'mystring' |cut -c1-5` is an alternative solution to ur problem.

more on [unix cut program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix))

Answer (score 65):

Works here:

```
$ TESTSTRINGONE="MOTEST"
$ NEWTESTSTRING=${TESTSTRINGONE:0:5}
$ echo ${NEWTESTSTRING}
MOTES
```

What shell are you using?

Comment: ok, it works fine in the terminal but it gives the error when i run it from a .sh script

Comment: Maybe your script is not executed by bash but by some less capable shell.

Comment: Have you tried adding `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` to your first line?

Comment: Yeah I tried adding both of them in with no luck, it just dose not make any sense :(

Comment: try both ways /shellscriptname.sh and sh shellscriptname.sh

Comment: I bet `.sh` or `#!/bin/sh` activate "POSIX compliance mode" of Bash. Since this form of string slicing isn't a POSIX shell feature (it's a Bash feature), that gets lost. Try explicitly setting the top line to `#!/bin/bash`, *not* `sh`.

Comment: Which version of Bash are you using? Bash <4 is missing lots of good stuff

Answer (score 15):

Substrings with `${variablename:0:5}` are a bash feature, not available in basic shells.  Are you sure you're running this under bash?  Check the shebang line (at the beginning of the script), and make sure it's `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`. And make sure you don't run it with the `sh` command (i.e. `sh scriptname`), since that overrides the shebang.

Comment: It was one of the first things I tried, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you:

```
 printf "%.5s" $TESTSTRINGONE
```

Comment: Is this POSIX? Having trouble groking the `printf` utility POSIX page

Answer (score 7):

Works in most shells

```
TESTSTRINGONE="MOTEST"
NEWTESTSTRING=${TESTSTRINGONE%"${TESTSTRINGONE#?????}"}
echo ${NEWTESTSTRING}
# MOTES
```

Comment: Until bashisms are accepted by POSIX, +1 for portability (even though the title of this thread specified bash).  I like to see these kinds of answers to raise awareness that all the world is not bash.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo $TESTSTRINGONE|awk '{print substr($0,0,5)}'
```

Answer (score 4):

You were so close! Here is the easiest solution: `NEWTESTSTRING=$(echo ${TESTSTRINGONE::5})`

So for your example:

```
$ TESTSTRINGONE="MOTEST"
$ NEWTESTSTRING=$(echo ${TESTSTRINGONE::5})
$ echo $NEWTESTSTRING
MOTES
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sed` if you like -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] TESTSTRINGONE="MOTEST"
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' <<< "$TESTSTRINGONE"
MOTES
```

Comment: I think you mean `sed 's/\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' <<<$TESTSTRINGONE`

Comment: Yeah, my string was truncated to begin with. Ill update it … Thanks @potong

Answer (score 1):

That parameter expansion should work (what version of bash do you have?)

Here's another approach:

```
read -n 5 NEWTESTSTRING <<< "$TESTSTRINGONE"
```

Answer (score 1):

The original syntax will work with BASH but not with DASH. On debian systems you
might think you are using bash, but maybe dash instead. If /bin/dash/exist then
try temporarily renaming dash to something like no.dash, and then create soft a
link, aka ln -s /bin/bash /bin/dash and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

expr substr $string $position $length

$position starts from 1